# Unity Changing material color on multiple gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a right click menu and i want to make objects change material color while i have my mouse on a button in that menu.

This is the code:

```
Color[] startCo;

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(myMenu.selected.title);

    for (int i = 0; i < startCo.Length; i++)
    {
        startCo[i] = objects[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;
    }

    foreach (GameObject obj in objects)
    {
        obj.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(myMenu.selected.title);

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
    {
        objects[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = startCo[i];
    }
}
```

With first for loop it does not work at all, but without it, when I put my mouse on the button, it makes material colors red, but it won't change it back to orginal.

My question is, is there any better way to save original colors with using *foreach*?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "does not work at all". Does it show build errors? From first look I would think that `objects[i].gameObject` does make no sense. Does that even compile? `objects[i]` already is the GameObject, so `objects[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>` should work just fine.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert, by "does not work at all", I mean It will not even change material colors to red (without using it, it changes it). "objects[i].gameObject" compiles in the both ways, i have just checked it. But I don't know how to change material color to the original.

Comment: If that is the case you most an error in your for loop most likely a `null reference error`

Comment: Either `startCo` is null or `startCo.Length` is zero the first time `OnPointerEnter` is called.

Comment: You might want to change `for (int i = 0; i < startCo.Length; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)` in your `OnPointerEnter` handler. But, you'll need to do something about allocating the array first. (I've been in C++ land for awhile; not sure about the C# mechanism here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version. It basically does exactly the same thing as your version, but makes sure to initialize the color array before using it (which was probably your main issue). It also keeps a copy of the list of objects whose colors were replaced, which is important in case new objects with a matching tag are created, or existing one's deleted. Finally, it adds a few safeguards to make it more robust in case you want to use `ReplaceColors()` and `RestoreColors()` in other places, too.

```
GameObject[] objectsWithReplacedColors;
Color[] originalColors;

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    ReplaceColors(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(myMenu.selected.title), Color.red);
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    RestoreColors();
}

private void ReplaceColors(GameObject[] forObjects, Color withColor)
{
    if (objectsWithReplacedColors != null)    // if there are already objects with replaced colors, we have to restore those first, or their original color would be lost
        RestoreColors();

    objectsWithReplacedColors = forObjects;
    originalColors = new Color[objectsWithReplacedColors.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < objectsWithReplacedColors.Length; i++)
    {
        originalColors[i] = objects[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;
        objectsWithReplacedColors[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = withColor;
    }
}

private void RestoreColors()
{
    if (objectsWithReplacedColors == null)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < objectsWithReplacedColors.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objectsWithReplacedColors[i])    // check if the objects still exists (it may have been deleted since its color was replaced)
            objectsWithReplacedColors[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = originalColors[i];
    }

    objectsWithReplacedColors = null;
    originalColors = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well my guess is you are finding objects every time these methods are called using `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` and i am pretty sure the order of these objects returned by `FindGameObjectsWithTag` is not specified so it can change ever time you call this method. This issue ends up giving you different original colors for different objects. My suggestion would be getting `objects`in the `Start`once and assigning colors to the array. Then use this array in `OnPointerExit`function.

Other than that your code and logic seems fine to me.

Comment: Kanet, What do you mean by getting objects in the Start? I mean, I understand what are you saying, but when I click my mouse, menu with three button shows (every button for another objects). This "myMenu.selected" means when I hover a button, one "class" of objects is selected and when I hover another button, another "class" of objects is selected etc.

Comment: Yeah but that should not matter because you probably have different tags for different "class" of objects. What you do here is also bad practice and causes issues to you. `myMenu.selected.title` should take care of that issue you are talking about. But for 1 button and objects for that button you initially know which objects to highlight so there is no need to update `objects` every time you hover that button.